# Testing Quartz CronTrigger trigger

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, quartz-scheduler

Assuming that I have a `CronTriggerBean` similar to

```
<bean id="midMonthCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="reminderJobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 6 15W * ?" />
</bean>
```

What is the best way to test that this bean will actually trigger at its specified date, *i.e.* on the weekday closest to the 15th of each month at 6 AM?

---

**Update**: This is supposed to be an unit test, so I'm not going to fire up a VM or change the system time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well firstly, there's no point in testing `CronTriggerBean` itself. It's part of the spring framework, and has already been tested.

A better test might be to test that your cron expression is what you expect. One option here is to use Quartz's `CronExpression` class. Given a `CronExpression` object, you can call `getNextValidTimeAfter(Date)`, which returns the next time after the given Date when the expression will fire.

Comment: Just to clarify - I'm not suggesting you change your code to use CronExpression, but that your unit test should use it.

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 7):

I used CronMaker only to be sure if my cron expression is well formed, check it out:
http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 3):

1. You can always wait until the 15h of July.
2. Being more serious... If it's really a key part of the application and I you need to have it tested fully. I would recommend using some **virtualization** setups and have the application installed within some guest machine. Then you could play with the system clock and test different date/times without spending a whole month on it. Moreover there's nothing that should stop you from **automating** such tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is supposed to be an unit test, so I'm not going to fire up a VM or change the system time.

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't use the Quartz scheduler, but instead use the `TaskSchedular` directly:

```
CronSequenceGenerator generator = new CronSequenceGenerator("0 0 8 */1 * *");
Date next = generator.next(prev);
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can get the trigger bean from spring and invoke the `getFireTimeAfter` method to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I found a cool documentation here about testing the `CronExpression`:
http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/10/testing-quartz-cron-expressions.html

The C# implementation will be something like this:

```
void Run()
{
    //var collection = findTriggerTimesRecursive(new CronExpression("0 0 17 L-3W 6-9 ? *"), DateTime.UtcNow);
    var collection = findTriggerTimesRecursive(new CronExpression("0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? *"), DateTime.UtcNow);
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public List<DateTimeOffset> findTriggerTimesRecursive(CronExpression expr, DateTimeOffset from, int max = 10)
{
    var times = new List<DateTimeOffset>();
    var next = expr.GetNextValidTimeAfter(from);

    while (next != null && times.Count < max)
    {
        times.Add(next.Value);
        from = next.Value;
        next = expr.GetNextValidTimeAfter(from);
    }

    return times;
}
```

This is a cool demo. But at the end, I end using Simple Schedule.

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .WithSimpleSchedule(
        x =>
        {
            x.WithIntervalInMinutes(15);
            x.RepeatForever();
        }
    )
    .ForJob("myJob", "group1")
    .Build();
```

Because this is executed immediately and then every x time.