# Java - spring - quatrz cron expression

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

Java - spring - quatz shedular.
I am trying to write following 2 cron expressions

```
1- cron expression to execute every day once in early morning by 3AM.
2 -cron expression to execute every after 3 hours
```

help appriciated

following are expressions i assume will work but have to wait to see.

```
1- "0 0 0/1 * * ?"
2- "0 3 * * * ?"
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060567/testing-quartz-crontrigger-trigger ? It seems that you can use CronSequenceGenerator.next()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expressions are wrong. The first one runs every hour while the second runs on every 3rd minute of every hour.

To run every day at 3 AM:

```
0 0 3 * * ?
```

I don't understand your second requirement.

Answer (score 2):

- 1) does not make any sense to me.
- 2) run in the 3th minute of every hour